# Want unique records - what is the SQL?

Tags: sql, phpactiverecord

I have this table

```
 User | File | SubmittedDate

 Joe    1223.txt  2011-11-12
 Joe    3321.txt  2011-11-13
 Jack   4332.txt  2012-11-22
 Jane   2344.txt  2012-11-10
```

I want to select so I only get one record of Joe's, one of Jack's, and one of Jane's.

e.g.

```
Joe    1223.txt  2011-11-12
Jack   4332.txt  2012-11-22
Jane   2344.txt  2012-11-10
```

In other words, I want a result set of rows that has a unique user field. What's the SQL to get this?

Comment: -1 for failure to demonstrate attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: -1 What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a better idea. I post an answerable question. Someone who knows the answer simply pastes it in. I give vote the answer and vote it up. Everyone wins.

Comment: Mihai gave the best answer. If he posts an answer below I will vote his as the best.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick Google search would show you there are several possible options:

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=select+unique+values+from+sql&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

One of which is to use the DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User FROM ....
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. :) I in fact did that quick Google search first. :) I was confused as to whether DISTINCT would in fact return unique rows if not *all* the fields of two rows were identical. Yes we could have gone back and forth talking about what I tried to do but there would less time wasted if I gave a straightforward question and got code I knew worked. I know there are SQL experts on this forum that will know exactly what I mean and simply post a link to an SQL fiddle. It's happened a few times so far.